# How to increase php file upload size

Tags: cakephp

Hi i implemented file upload in the cakePHP files are uploaded fine but my code does not 
  support to upload a file with size more than 1 Mb, i tried in the following way but there is
  no use.

I added the following lines in the .htaccess file

```
php_value post_max_size 10M
php_value upload_max_filesize 10M
```

and added the following lines in the upload() in TestController

```
 $post_max_size = ini_get('post_max_size');
 $upload_max_filesize = ini_get('upload_max_filesize');     
 LogUtil::$logger->debug('Post Maximum Size :  '. $post_max_size);
 LogUtil::$logger->debug('Upload Maximum Size :  '. $upload_max_filesize);
```

The loggers does not shown the modified vales for upload max filesize and postmaxsize

Please guide me, Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184513/php-change-the-maximum-upload-file-size try this

Comment: +1 is the best thank you in stack overflow.. give a +1 if its helpful

Answer (score 1):

open **php.ini** file.

find the **upload_max_filesize** in your php.ini file.

change the value based on requirement.

save the file.

restart the apache server.

now its working.